# Wordpress JQuery Issues with custom PHP file

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, header

I have created my own tabbed mega-menu for use on my website.

I add it into the 'header.php' as so

```
<div class="menubar">
    <?php
        include "main-menu.php";
    ?>
</div>
```

the menu.php file is made up as so (simplified):

```
<nav class="content">
    <ul class="exo-menu">
        <li class="active menhome"><a href="/" class="menhme"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> Brands</a>
            <div id="wrapper" class="animated fadeIn mega-menu hidden">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="Featured">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline list-inline2">
                                        <li><a data-filter=".89" href="/brand/brand-1/"><img src="https://www.example.com" alt="img"><span></span></a></li>                                          
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="AtoF">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">                                
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand-a/"><span>BRAND A</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="GtoN">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand-g/"><span>BRAND G</span></a></li>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="OtoW">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-2">
                                        <li><a href="/brand/brand-o/"><span>BRAND O</span></a></li>                                                                            
                                    </ul>                         
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">   
                            <li   class="active change"><a href="#Featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#AtoF" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"># - F</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#GtoN" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">G - N</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#OtoW" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">O - Z</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="mega-drop-down mega-drop-down-2"><a href="#" onclick="return false"><i class="fa"></i> CATEGORIES</a>
            <div id="wrapper2" class="animated fadeIn mega-menu mega-menu2 hidden">
                <div class="mega-menu-wrap">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-lg-12">
                                        <ul class="nav-list list-inline col-md-4">
                                        <li class="dropdown-header"><a href="/product-category/a/">A</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>    
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now to the problem... Wordpress loads JQuery by default and my menu requires JQuery to work when I hover over the tabs - Brands, categories... JQuery activates the drop-down mega menu.

However, my menu.php file does not seem to pick up the default loaded JQuery file.

As a result, I have added to the header.php:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This then sorts the issue for my menu.php file.

But, the fact I am calling an additional JQuery file in the header appears to be causing conflicts with other areas of the website.

Is there a way that I can force my menu to use the default JQuery which is loaded through WordPress?

I have added code to the bottom of the menu.php file to allow the tabs to work, this code works for both me desktop menu and also additional script for my mobile menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#toggle-search').on('click', function() {
      $('#searchform').toggle('display: inline-block');
    });
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper').removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper2').removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper3').removeClass('hidden');
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#wrapper4').removeClass('hidden');
    });

    jQuery(document).ready( function ( $ ){
        $(".change>a").hover( function () { 
            $(this)[0].click();
        }, 
        function () {
        /* code for mouseout */
        });
    }); 

        var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("mega-drop-down, drop-down");
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
            acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight){
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } 
    else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }    
}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Did you try using `jQuery(...)` (not `$(...)`)? That's how you're typically (almost always) going to use it in a Wordpress context. Also, why are you using 1.12? That's almost 3 years old. Do you get any errors? And, perhaps this is obvious, but if you must use your own jQuery, are you using [`noconflict` mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)?

Comment: Where is your jQuery code for menu?

Comment: @EdCottrellI understand Wordpress uses noconflict mode as default? and I have not changed that so I am assuming that no conflict mode is still active. Ideally though I would like to not have to add in my own JQuery file, id prefer that the menu works off of the default loaded JQuery that wordpress offers. although on the no conflict topic, the 2 JQuery files appear to be conflicting but I am unsure how to check if no conflict more is active or not

Comment: @RohitRasela I have added the script to the bottom of the question. this is used for the tabs. I have included the script in the menu.php file. I have also created a separate menu.js file but am facing the same problem as the JQuery file in that when i register menu.js with functions.php, menu.php file does not pick it up

Comment: You can create a js file for your code and load it in footer. After the default jQuery file and use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: The best approach is to put your code in a JS file and use `wp_enqueue-script` to load it and make jquery a dependency. Bad practice to start adding scripts manually in wordpress. You also need to account for wordpress themes using `jQuery.noConflict()` in your code. Also don't need `document.ready` for each statement...wrap them all in one

Comment: Very much what @charlietfl said.  Additionally, use a jQuery "no-conflict-safe" document ready, and you would be safe to use the `$` within:  `jQuery(function($) { // ... safe to use $ here.... });`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your jQuery.min.js loaded in  section.
Maybe your theme or plugin which uses jQuery makes it loaded on footer section. (if jQuery is loaded after your code then it won't work)
Please try below code to force jQuery loaded on header section.

```
function insert_jquery(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', false, array(), false, false);
}
add_filter('wp_enqueue_scripts','insert_jquery',1);
```